# SimpleXML returning nothing

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have a small script I am building using SimpleXML to parse a small XML file. I have several scripts that I use SimpleXML with and have no problems so I have used it before. So I am not sure why it's not working. When I do print_r($xml); to test it outputs the elements but I can't get it to parse the data otherwise.

This is the test XML I am using.

[XML FILE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/mesquite.xml)

Here is the snippet of the SimpleXML

```
//Set path to data file
$data = "http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/mesquite.xml";

// Lets parse the XML feed
$xml = simplexml_load_file($data);

//Set initial output to false
    $tData = false;
foreach($xml->entry as $entry){

    $fname = $entry->fname;
    $lname = $entry->lname;
    $location = $entry->location;
    $report = $entry->report;
    $description = $entry->description;
```

If anyone needs to see the entire script here it is.

```
  <?php
#######################################################################################
#
#  MESQUITE STORM REPORTS
#  version 1.00
#
#  This program is free and no license is required.
#
#
#  mesquiteweather.net
#
#######################################################################################

////  SETTINGS  ////


////  SETTINGS  ////

$bkgColor                                       = '#d4d4d4';  // Background color   Examples:  "gray"  "#CCC"   "#CCCCCC"
$bc                                             = '#EEEEEE';  // Background color of table cells
$dtColor                                        = '#FFF';     // Date & time color  Examples:   "#FC0"   "#FFCC00"   "white"
$width                                          = '100%';     // Set the width of the report tables

////  END OF SETTINGS  ////


#######################################################################################

ini_set('display_errors','1');

## Start Configurable data ##

//Set path to data file
$data = "http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/mesquite.xml";

## End Configurable data ##

// overrides from the Carter Lake Settings.php file (if applicable)
global $SITE;
if(isset($SITE['cacheFileDir'])) {$cacheFileDir = $SITE['cacheFileDir']; }
if (isset($SITE['imagesDir']))   {$imagesDir = $SITE['imagesDir'];}
if(isset ($SITE['tz']))          {$ourTZ = $SITE['tz'];}
if(!function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    putenv("TZ=" . $ourTZ);
}
else
{
    date_default_timezone_set("$ourTZ");
}

// get path info & protect for cross-site scripting vulnerability
$sri = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? str_replace('#SA', '', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) : '';

// set borders
   $bbrdr = 'border-bottom:thin solid black';       // bottom
   $lbrdr = 'border-left:thin solid black';         // left
   $rbrdr = 'border-right:thin solid black';        // right
   $tbrdr = 'border-top:thin solid black';          // top
   $sbrdr = 'border-right:thin solid black; '.
            'border-left:thin solid black';         // side

//Define table to display after each storm report
$afterTable = "<table style='margin-bottom: 5px;' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tbody><tr><td><img alt='' src='images/1pixel.gif' border='0' height='7' width='7'></td><td class='shadow-mid' width='100%'><img alt='' src='images/1pixel.gif' border='0' height='7' width='7'></td><td><img alt='' src='images/1pixel.gif' border='0' height='7' width='7'></td></tr><tbody></table>\n";

// Let's assign the table some styles
   $noMessageStyle                              = "width:{$width}; text-align:center; margin:0px auto; background-color:{$bkgColor};";
   $td1Style                                    = "{$tbrdr};{$sbrdr}; padding:2px 0px 2px 6px;  background-image:url({$imagesDir}headerbgd2.gif); color:{$dtColor};";
   $td2Style                                    = "{$sbrdr}; padding:6px 0px 0px 6px;";
   $td3Style                                    = "{$sbrdr}; line-height:5px;";
   $td4Style                                    = "{$sbrdr}; {$bbrdr}; padding: 2px 6px 6px 6px;";


//Set message to display if there were not report
    $noStormMessage                                     .= "<table style='{$noMessageStyle}' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>\n";
    $noStormMessage                                     .= "<tbody>\n";
    $noStormMessage                                     .= "  <tr><td style='{$td1Style}'>LIVE STORM REPORTS</td></tr>\n";
    $noStormMessage                                     .= "  <tr><td style='{$td4Style}'>There are currently no storm reports for Mesquite</td></tr>\n";
    $noStormMessage                                     .= "</tbody>\n";
    $noStormMessage                                     .= "</table>\n";
    $noStormMessage                                     .= $afterTable;

// Lets parse the XML feed
$xml = simplexml_load_file($data);

//Set initial output to false
    $tData = false;
foreach($xml->entry as $entry){

    $fname = $entry->fname;
    $lname = $entry->lname;
    $location = $entry->location;
    $report = $entry->report;
    $description = $entry->description;

// Set table style
   $tableStyle = "width: 100%; margin:0px auto; background-color:{$bkgColor};";
   $td1Style = "{$tbrdr};{$sbrdr}; padding:2px 0px 2px 6px;  background-image:url({$imagesDir}headerbgd2.gif); color:{$dtColor};";
   $td2Style = "{$sbrdr}; padding:6px 0px 0px 6px; background-color:{$reportColor};";
   $td3Style = "{$sbrdr}; line-height:5px; background-color:{$reportColor};";
   $td4Style = "{$sbrdr}; {$bbrdr}; padding: 2px 6px 6px 6px; background-color:{$reportColor};";


 // construct data for table display
    $tData .= "<table style='{$tableStyle}' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>\n";
    $tData .= "<tbody>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr><td style='{$td1Style}'><b>{$report}</b></td></tr>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr>\n";
    $tData .= "    <td style='{$td2Style}'>Reported By: <b>{$fname} {$lname}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Location: <b>{$location}</b></td>\n";
    $tData .= "  </tr>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr><td style='{$td3Style}'>&nbsp;</td></tr>\n";
    $tData .= "  <tr><td style='{$td4Style}'>Description: <b>{$description}</b></td></tr>\n";
    $tData .= "</tbody>\n";
    $tData .= "</table>\n";
    $tData .=  $afterTable;

 }

//If no storms were in the source, set no storm message
if(!$tData)
{
    $tData = $noStormMessage;
}

echo $tData;

?>
```

I am not sure what I am missing or overlooking. I have done this many times. Any suggestions?

-Thanks

Comment: Can we see the results of the print_r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `entry` is not an element in your `$xml` object. It's the root element. So you can don't need a loop:

```
$fname = $xml->fname;
$lname = $xml->lname;
$location = $xml->location;
$report = $xml->report;
$description = $xml->description;
```

You could next the multiple `entry` elements in a parent element then your original code would work.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML file you link to is indeed a representative of the full file, then your problem is here: `$xml->entry`.

SimpleXML does not have a separate object representing the document, the object you get when you load an XML string or file is the root element of that file. In other words, `$xml` **is** the `<entry>` node.

So you just need to say `$xml->fname`, `$xml->lname`, etc.

An XML file can only have one "root element", so there would be no way for `foreach ( $xml->entry ...` to work unless there was some container outside `<entry>` in the input file.